# Define Timezone dynamically for a native Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, timezone, quarkus, utc

I am retrieving a `DATE` field from a mariadb database table. I am specifically not using `TIMESTAMP`, because the business requirement is a date without time. I want to use UTC for all calculations and be independent from any timezone. The database is using UTC. The production environment JVM is using UTC too, and all seemed fine. Now when running an Integration test locally on my computer that uses the CET timezone, the integration test broke, so I identified that I have an issue here.

I could of course start up the JVM with `-Duser.timezone=UTC` but this still feels really error-prone. I could also set `quarkus.hibernate-orm.jdbc.timezone=UTC` in my `application.properties` but again: this does not feel like THE perfect solution either. I think there should be a way to dynamically for the native query to define the timezone to be used.

Is there a more stable solution?

For instance, is there something dynamically in th sense of:
Query query = this.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(MY_QUERY);
query.setTimezone("UTC");

This way, the code would always work, independent from JVM or any startup properties or parameters.

Comment: What about the two solutions you mentioned feels error-prone to you? What errors do you foresee?

Comment: That a different application.properties is used, or that the JVM is NT started with the user.timezone=UTC setting. This will produce wrong data, and might not even be noticed.